# Google Drive API: No Parents with drive.files.get

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API.  I can get a list of files with the drive.files.list API method.  Here is the result of a call to this method:

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1yLJFT2bHhsz1WxJX29mD9DiNz0vLDlBvzJf5GJCcboI",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
   "parents": [
    "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQRld6RWljU0Y4TG8"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQVXdBRmlPMGNoTmM",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "parents": [
    "0B4jAnSzS-VxlZW9RcDJheU5FYW8"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQRld6RWljU0Y4TG8",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "parents": [
    "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQQndiQnYxbUF4SjQ"
   ]
  }]
}
```

When I request individual files using the drive.files.get API call, I would expect to get the same results as shown in the list above.  I do when I request the first and third file listed.  For example:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0Bwy7SlKkxnwQRld6RWljU0Y4TG8?supportsTeamDrives=true&fields=id%2CmimeType%2Cparents

Result:

```
{
 "id": "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQRld6RWljU0Y4TG8",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
 "parents": [
  "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQQndiQnYxbUF4SjQ"
 ]
}
```

This is identical to what is shown in the list.  But for some reason when I request the second file in the list, the parents list is missing from the result:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0Bwy7SlKkxnwQVXdBRmlPMGNoTmM?supportsTeamDrives=true&fields=id%2CmimeType%2Cparents

Result:

```
{
 "id": "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQVXdBRmlPMGNoTmM",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

No parents array.  Can anyone explain this behavior?  I assumed all files should have a parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done yet, you may want to check if you have an access to the parent of your second file. As stated in [Enabling Team Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-teamdrives):

> A parent does not appear in the parents list if the requesting user is a not a member of the Team Drive and does not have access to the parent.

In [Behavioral differences](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-teamdrives#behavioral_differences), fields related to permissions and ownership are populated differently.

Comment: It's possible that I am not a member of the Team Drive since I am accessing through the API using a Service Account, but I still don't understand why some files have parents and others do not.  And why can I always see the parents when getting a list?  If I shouldn't be able to see a parent when requesting an individual file, why do I see a parent when requesting a list of files?